# Combing two SQL where statements in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I make both of these WHERE statements be satisfied please?

```
where("cast(strftime('%d', date) as int) = ?", month)
where("cast(strftime('%Y', date) as int) = ?", year)
```

Something like:

```
where("cast(strftime('%d', date) as int) = ?", month) AND
       where("cast(strftime('%Y', date) as int) = ?", year)
```

I have tried a few ways but can't get it working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple question marks:

```
where("cast(strftime('%d', date) as int) = ? 
       AND cast(strftime('%Y', date) as int) = ?", month, year)
```

Or just use 2 `where` statements:

```
where("cast(strftime('%d', date) as int) = ?", month)
.where("cast(strftime('%Y', date) as int) = ?", year)
```